# ggvis integration with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

This is rather a simple question. I read other threads, and found that, in order to insert a GGVIS visualization into Shiny, you need:

1. In `ui.R` - Call `ggvisOutput("EvolucionVisitas")`
2. In `server.R` - use function `bind_shiny("EvolucionVisitas")`

I'm having problems plotting the graph for my tab "Evolución Visitas".
I did both, but i'm failing somewhere.

Nothing prints in my tab: EvoluciónVisitas. Everything else is okay.

Here is my data:

```
structure(list(date = structure(1:31, .Label = c("2014-12-01", 
"2014-12-02", "2014-12-03", "2014-12-04", "2014-12-05", "2014-12-06", 
"2014-12-07", "2014-12-08", "2014-12-09", "2014-12-10", "2014-12-11", 
"2014-12-12", "2014-12-13", "2014-12-14", "2014-12-15", "2014-12-16", 
"2014-12-17", "2014-12-18", "2014-12-19", "2014-12-20", "2014-12-21", 
"2014-12-22", "2014-12-23", "2014-12-24", "2014-12-25", "2014-12-26", 
"2014-12-27", "2014-12-28", "2014-12-29", "2014-12-30", "2014-12-31"
), class = "factor"), sessions = c(1932L, 1828L, 2349L, 8192L, 
3188L, 3277L, 2846L, 2541L, 5434L, 4290L, 2059L, 2080L, 2111L, 
3776L, 1989L, 1844L, 3641L, 1283L, 1362L, 1568L, 2882L, 1212L, 
957L, 851L, 928L, 1435L, 1115L, 1471L, 1128L, 1022L, 768L), id = 1:31), .Names = c("date", 
"sessions", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -31L), drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here my code, thanks.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

# Define the overall UI
shinyUI(

  # Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
  fluidPage(    

    # Give the page a title
    br(),
    br(),
    titlePanel("Visitas por fuente"),

    # Generate a row with a sidebar
    sidebarLayout(      

      # Define the sidebar with one input



      sidebarPanel(
        dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date range"),
                       start = "2014-12-01", end = "2014-12-31")

      ),


      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel('Visitas por fuente',
                   plotOutput("VisitasFuente")),
          tabPanel('Evolución de las visitas',
                   ggvisOutput("EvolucionVisitas")),
          tabPanel('Comentarios',
                   dataTableOutput("Comentarios"))
        )

    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)



Visitas_Por_Fuente <- read.csv("D:\\RCoursera\\Star-App-2\\Visitas_Por_Fuente_Dic.csv")
labelsF = c("Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", "Campañas", "Adwords")
Visitas_Por_Fuente$date <- as.Date(Visitas_Por_Fuente$date)
ComentariosDic <- read.csv("D:\\RCoursera\\Star-App-2\\ComentariosDic2014.csv",header = TRUE, sep = ";")
ComentariosDic$date <- as.Date(ComentariosDic$date)


shinyServer(


  function(input, output) {



    output$VisitasFuente <- renderPlot({

      # Filter the data based on user selection month     
      date_seq <- seq(input$dates[1], input$dates[2], by = "day")


      VisitasData <- filter(Visitas_Por_Fuente, date %in% date_seq  & Fuentes %in% labelsF)

      VisitasData <- VisitasData %>% group_by(Fuentes) %>%
                                     summarise(sessions = sum(sessions))




      # Bar graph using ggplot2 library 
      ggplot(VisitasData, aes(factor(Fuentes), sessions, fill = Fuentes)) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
        geom_text(aes(label = comma(sessions)), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
        scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("0", "1", "3", "6", "9", "12", "15"),
                          labels = labelsF,
                          values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
                                     "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#A082F8", "#F072A2"))

    })

    **############# Evolución de las visitas ##############################################
    #####################################################################################**


    output$EvolucionVisitas <- renderPlot({

      # Filter the data based on user selection month     
      date_seq <- seq(input$dates[1], input$dates[2], by = "day")


      EvolucionVisitas <-  filter(Visitas_Por_Fuente, date %in% date_seq) 


      mysessions <- function(x) {
        if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
        #notice below the id column is how ggvis can understand which session to show 
        row <- EvolucionVisitas[EvolucionVisitas$id == x$id, ]
        #prettyNum shows the number with thousand-comma separator  
        paste0("Sessions:", "&nbsp;",prettyNum(row$sessions, big.mark=",",scientific=F)) 
      }




      EvolucionVisitas %>% 
        ggvis(x= ~date, y= ~sessions, key := ~id) %>%
        layer_points()  %>%
        add_tooltip(mysessions ,"hover") %>%
        layer_paths() %>%
        add_axis("x", value=c(as.character(EvolucionVisitas$date[1]),as.character(EvolucionVisitas$date[round(length(EvolucionVisitas$date)/2,0)]),
                              as.character(tail(EvolucionVisitas$date, n=1)))) %>%
        bind_shiny("EvolucionVisitas")







    #####################################################################################
    #####################################################################################


    output$Comentarios = renderDataTable({

      date_seq <- seq(input$dates[1], input$dates[2], by = "day")


      ComentariosDic <- filter(ComentariosDic, date %in% date_seq)

      ComentariosDic <- filter(ComentariosDic, !grepl("^$", Comentarios))


    })

})
```

Comment: Your data is not reproducible, `Fuentes` is missing from your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only troubleshooting the ggvis, your problem is primarily a result of your attempt to customize the x-axis.  The `ggvis` is trying to be smart by interpreting the dates as times.  For the purposes of this plot, I believe it would be best to treat them as factors.

Here is a complete reproducible answer.

```
shiny::runGist("https://gist.github.com/cdeterman/0ac102cd68a7987a8a90")
```

You will notice a few other differences.  It is probably best to make your dataset reactive so you can reuse it in multiple places without additional overhead.  Also, as @jalapic initially suggested, you want to make your `ggvis` object reactive so the plot can be dynamic and use the nice tooltips.

Comment: may you separate "ui.R" from "server.R", please. I'll try this at home, later. Thanks.

Comment: @OmarGonzales, I separated the files, does this solution work for you?

Comment: @cderterman, i've tried and got: "Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4457
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  'match' requires vector arguments". I can't fully test it, all give it a try later. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @OmarGonzales, AH! I simply forgot to include the packages.  I have edited my answer to just be a gist like cory to be more concise.

Comment: Thanks, i choose this because it explain my errors, and give exactly the output desired (with correct x label). I just change round() to ceiling() for the middle X label.

Comment: just want to ask: why my code worked well just with ggvis? And why not within Shiny? May you elaborate a little more on his point. Thanks!

Comment: @OmarGonzales, it is difficult to say.  I suspect something to do with reactives?  However the x-axis formatting should have been an issue in both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Where you have the code in server.R starting

```
  output$EvolucionVisitas <- renderPlot({
```

you could try wrapping it in a reactive like this, rather than in `renderPlot`:

```
vis <- reactive({

# Filter the data based on user selection month     
      date_seq <- seq(input$dates[1], input$dates[2], by = "day")


      EvolucionVisitas <-  filter(Visitas_Por_Fuente, date %in% date_seq) 


      mysessions <- function(x) {
        if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
        #notice below the id column is how ggvis can understand which session to show 
        row <- EvolucionVisitas[EvolucionVisitas$id == x$id, ]
        #prettyNum shows the number with thousand-comma separator  
        paste0("Sessions:", "&nbsp;",prettyNum(row$sessions, big.mark=",",scientific=F)) 
      }

myvis <-
    ggvis(x= ~date, y= ~sessions, key := ~id) %>%
        layer_points()  %>%
        add_tooltip(mysessions ,"hover") %>%
        layer_paths() %>%
        add_axis("x", 

    value=c(as.character(EvolucionVisitas$date[1]),as.character(EvolucionVisitas$date[round(length(EvolucionVisitas$date)/2,0)]),
                                  as.character(tail(EvolucionVisitas$date, n=1)))) 


    myvis
    })
```

Then outside of the reactive put :

```
vis %>% bind_shiny("EvolucionVisitas")
```

I think I recall something similar when I was doing a shiny/ggvis - my code is on my github here: https://github.com/jalapic/shinyapps/tree/master/soccerteams  it might be of help.

Comment: i think your missing to apply the ggvis code to the data frame. I've tried what did you say, but still, nothing prints.

Comment: Oh well, i have found that often i need to put my ggvis code into a reactive expression when using interactive tooltips and then bind shiny to that reactive.  - perhaps your problem is something else

Answer (score 0):

Whew... that's a bit of a mess. I stripped it down to the ggvis part and tried to get it running. Check it out in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/corynissen/f75ecae388f81be13436).

You can run it with:

```
shiny::runGist("https://gist.github.com/corynissen/f75ecae388f81be13436")
```

Comment: i've tried this, but is not reactive with the dateinputRange buttons... but the graphic does not change, when changing date. May you look up for that? Thanks! –

Comment: Oh, I figured you could get that running. I've updated the gist. The chart is interactive with the date picker now.

Comment: it works perfect. Just the x labels, needs to show only the first, middle, and last dates within the range selected, and it its actually not doing that. I'm at work now, so i cannot fully test it. I'll check it carfully later. Thanks man.